# prevent linebreaks between two elements

Tags: html, css

I have this html with css: http://jsfiddle.net/krhxG/

I set the width of the div to 20px in purpose in order to explain what I need.
How can I prevent from the submit button to break the line?
I want both the controls to be as one without line breaks at all. How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *How can I prevent from the submit button to break the line?*

With a `white-space: nowrap;` on the parent `<div>` [See updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krhxG/1/).

Answer (score 1):

In your container div, you need a white-space property:

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap;">
<input type="text" /><input type="submit" value=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @BalusC answer in some weird cases (e.g. html generated and inserted by JavaScript)  you also may want to try to insert a zero width joiner:

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 290px;   
  white-space: no-wrap;
  resize:both;
  overflow:auto; 
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.breakable-text{
  display: inline;
  white-space: no-wrap;
}

.no-break-before {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="breakable-text">Lorem dorem tralalalala LAST_WORD</span>&#8205;<span class="no-break-before">TOGETHER</span>
</div>
```